# predefined parameters in function

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters

been looking but not much luck, i want to create a function that only allows certain items to be passed as the first parameter.

e.g. it should only allow the following strings:

```
"error", "warning", "info"
```

then the call would be

```
showme("error");
or showme("warning");
or showme("info");
```

can this be done?  I know I can define

```
showme(string type){}
```

but ideally I need `showme(string type "error"){}`

Comment: why not use enums, and switch accordingly?

Comment: dude more detail, you q is not clear enough. i can not under stand you

Comment: Thanks Rozuur I was uncertain on the usage, Ali sorry but the question is very clear and even given examples!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest an [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx)

```
public enum ErrorType {
    error,
    warning,
    info
}

public void ShowMe(ErrorType errorType) {
    switch (errorType) {
        case ErrorType.error:
        //do stuff
        break;
        case ErrorType.warning:
        //do stuff
        break;
        case ErrorType.info:
        //do stuff
        break;
        default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument supplied");
        break;
    }
}

//Invoke the method
ShowMe(ErrorType.info);
```

Comment: Note that using an enum *does not* prevent other values than `error`, `warning` and `info` being passed to `ShowMe`.

Comment: @dtb, Can you explain a bit further? In my example above, wouldn't the compiler generate an error if a type other than `ErrorType` was passed to `ShowMe`?

Comment: Yes, the compiler would generate an error if a type other than `ErrorType` was passed to `ShowMe`. But I was talking about values of type `ErrorType` other than  `ErrorType.error`, `ErrorType.warning` and `ErrorType.info`. For example, you can pass `(ErrorType)42` to `ShowMe` without any compile-time or runtime error. That's why you need a `default` case.

Comment: @dtb, Ahh. My mind isn't able to think so deviously this early in the morning. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks James, accepted as the answer, wasn't sure how to use Enums as parameters, I knew it had something to do with it but couldn't work it out.

@dtb: How would you do default values in this instance?

Comment: @Neo: Throw an ArgumentException.

Comment: Updated to reflect @dtb's answer to your additional question.

Answer (score 3):

As per Rozuur's comment, an Enum would be a clean option. Failing that you could try using code contracts: http://www.cauldwell.net/patrick/blog/CodeContracts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up the logic that depends on your set of values into a class with private constructor, and retrieve instances either through singleton properties or through a factory method.

Something like:

```
public class StringConstraint
{
   private StringConstraint()
   public static readonly StringConstraint error = new StringConstraint()
   ...

   public void DoStuffWithStringValue()
   {
      // Here you do the logic that depends on your particular string value
      // e.g. (always) log a message as an error
   }
}
```

This obliges you to only ever pass instances that conform to the logic you want to implement for each of your three strings.